# How to ensure when time arrive Quartz job has an available thread

Tags: triggers, quartz-scheduler

Is  there a way to  ensure that when a trigger fire time arrived it has always  a thread to run on.triggers has priority but this not  guarantee  ,and i giving more thread then max number of job is not an option.I have lots of job but one of them must run at specified time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate scheduler for the job. So the important job will always have a free thread, because nobody else would use it.

Comment: is it possible apply different configuration to scheduler  instances

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Which configuration? What could be impossible?

Comment: quartz.properties   file which is used for configuring quartz .Like       org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 6  ,Are you using quartz with spring ?

Comment: Yes, I use the Spring. If you don't, as I see then you could use StdSchedulerFactory with an alternative properties file.